# how to add regression line and regression line equation on graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the below input file and the code/script to add the regression line on the graph but the code gives this error:`ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension`. I couldn't figure out that error.

How can I add the regression line and regression line equation on graph?

**Input file:**

```
-5.06   -4.27
-6.69   -7.28
-3.80   -3.51
-3.88   -2.79
-0.90   -0.81
 2.10    2.59
-1.08    0.28
-5.00   -3.39
 2.67    2.92
 2.48    2.85
-5.10   -3.49
 2.88    3.09
 2.30    2.67
-3.47   -2.20
-0.90   -0.79
```

**Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
import pylab as plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy, scipy, pylab, random
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
from scipy import stats

with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    x=[]
    y=[]

    for line in f:
        if not line.strip() or line.startswith('@') or line.startswith('#'): continue
        row = line.split()
        x.append(float(row[0]))
        y.append(float(row[1]))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(2.2,2.2), dpi=300)
ax = plt.subplot(111)

plt.xlim(4, -8)
plt.ylim(4, -8)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(6))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(6))

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(1))


#regression part
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)
line = slope*x+intercept
plt.plot(x, line, 'r', label='fitted line')
#end

plt.scatter(x,y,color=['black','black','black','black','black','black','black','black','black','black','black','black','black','black','black'], s=3.5)


plt.savefig("output.png", dpi=300)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot multiply a list with a float number. So you may create a numpy array from the input list `x`,

```
line = slope*np.array(x)+intercept
```

More ideally you would read in your data using `np.genfromtxt`,

```
x,y = np.genfromtxt("input.txt", unpack=True)
```

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
from scipy import stats

x,y = np.genfromtxt("input.txt", unpack=True) 

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(2.2,2.2), dpi=300)
ax = plt.subplot(111)

plt.xlim(4, -8)
plt.ylim(4, -8)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(6))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(6))

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(1))


#regression part
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x,y)

line = slope*x+intercept
plt.plot(x, line, 'r', label='y={:.2f}x+{:.2f}'.format(slope,intercept))
#end

plt.scatter(x,y, color="k", s=3.5)
plt.legend(fontsize=9)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That works but the regression line doesn't cover all the points on the graph (e.g. last point). Seems that the regression line is short a bit. Is there something missing in the code?

Comment: No, it *is* covering the coordinates of all points. It may make sense to sort the points, `plt.plot(np.sort(x), line[np.argsort(x)],)`, but since you are plotting a straight line, this is optional.

Comment: Of course you can expand the range of x values to evaluate your regression line to, `xc = np.linspace(4,-8); line = slope*xc+intercept; 
plt.plot(xc, line,)` in case this is what you're after.

Comment: Do you know how to add correlation coefficient on the graph as well (it would be something like this: cor=0.93 in the legend)?

Comment: What is the problem of adding any other stuff on the legend? What have you tried and in how far did it fail?

Comment: I couldn't find the required code to get the correlation coefficient. That is the issue.

Comment: Is `r_value` not what you mean by correlation coefficient?

Comment: Yes, how can I add it on the legend (e.g. cor=0.93)?

Comment: In the same way you add the other two values.

Answer (score 1):

You could try and add this piece of code for the regression line:

```
# To plot the regression line
plt.plot(X, (B0 + B1*x), label = 'y = {:.2f} + {:.2f}*x'.format(B0, B1))
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
```

Here is a screenshot of the visualization for the Linear Regression code I had written:

[image]